# How to Check the Validation of a Message ID

Tags: pyrogram

I used these code:

```
if message.empty:
    return
message.forward(archiveid)
```

I hope that if messages has been deleted before excicute these codes, message.empty will be true. But message.empty is still "None" after deleting that message in telegram.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you set up a message handler, your `message` variable (the Telegram Message) will be the Message you received. *It does not change afterwards!* If you want to make sure the message still exists when you handle it, you have to call `get_messages()` on it.

```py
@app.on_message()
def message_handler(client, message):
    m = client.get_messages(message.chat.id, message.message_id)
    if m.empty:
        do_stuff()  # placeholder for your own logic
```

The result of the above `get_messages()` call would look like this if it was empty:

```py
{
    "_": "Message",
    "message_id": 2465190,
    "empty": true
}
```